How can I optimize ProductCard component and its render method in React
ExclusiveOffers swiper:
export const ExclusiveOffers = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { category } = useParams();
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetProductsQuery(category);

  const memoizedProducts = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array.isArray(data?.data) &&
      data.data.filter((product: Product) => product.productId < 7),

    [data]
  );

  return (
    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" gap="2rem">
      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between">
        <Typography variant="h2">Exclusive Offers</Typography>
        <Typography
          variant="subtitle1"
          component={Link}
          to={`/${category}/all`}
          sx={{ color: theme.palette.primary.main, cursor: "pointer" }}
        >
          See all
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box className="container-two">
        <Swiper
          cssMode={true}
          mousewheel={true}
          keyboard={true}
          spaceBetween={10}
          modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Mousewheel, Keyboard]}
          className="swiper-container"
        >
          {!isLoading ? (
            memoizedProducts.map((product: Product) => (
              <SwiperSlide>
                <ProductCard
                  key={product.productId}
                  product={product}
                  isLoading={isLoading}
                />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))
          ) : (
            <>
              {Array.from({ length: 7 }).map((_, index) => (
                <SwiperSlide>
                  <ProductCard key={index} isLoading={isLoading} />
                </SwiperSlide>
              ))}
            </>
          )}
        </Swiper>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

AllProductsPage:
export const AllProductsPage = () => {
  const { category } = useParams();
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetProductsQuery(category);

  return (
    <Box
      display="flex"
      flexWrap="wrap"
      justifyContent="center"
      gap="10px"
      marginTop={10}
      padding={{
        xs: "0 16px 48px 16px",
        sm: "0 24px 48px 24px",
        md: "0 48px 48px 48px",
      }}
    >
      {!isLoading ? (
        data.data.map((product: Product) => (
          <Box
            key={product.productId}
            width={{
              xs: "216px !important",
              md: "224px !important",
            }}
            height={{
              xs: "269.46px !important",
              md: "289.46px !important",
            }}
            padding="1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem"
            display="flex"
            flexDirection="column"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            borderRadius="1rem"
            bgcolor="#ffffff"
            sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          >
            <ProductCard
              key={product.productId}
              product={product}
              isLoading={isLoading}
            />
          </Box>
        ))
      ) : (
        <>
          {Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, index) => (
            <Box
              key={index}
              width={{
                xs: "216px !important",
                md: "224px !important",
              }}
              height={{
                xs: "269.46px !important",
                md: "289.46px !important",
              }}
              padding="1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem"
              display="flex"
              flexDirection="column"
              alignItems="center"
              justifyContent="space-between"
              borderRadius="1rem"
              bgcolor="#ffffff"
              sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            >
              <ProductCard key={index} isLoading={isLoading} />
            </Box>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

ProductCard:
export const ProductCard = ({ product, isLoading }: ProductCardProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading ? (
        <>
          <Box
            component="img"
            src={product?.imgURL}
            alt="product"
            width={{ xs: 130, sm: 150 }}
            height={{ xs: 130, sm: 150 }}
          />
          <Box>
            <Typography
              variant="h2"
              fontSize="1.2rem !important"
              textAlign="center"
            >
              {product?.name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="subtitle1"
              fontSize="13.5px !important"
              textAlign="center"
            >
              {product?.quantity}pcs, Pricetag
            </Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box
            width="100%"
            display="flex"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="space-between"
          >
            <Typography variant="h2" fontSize="1.2rem !important">
              ${product?.price}
            </Typography>
            <Button
              sx={{
                minWidth: "1.8rem",
                maxWidth: "1.8rem",
                height: "1.8rem",
                borderRadius: "0.3rem",
              }}
            >
              <AddIcon sx={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }} />
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Skeleton
            variant="rectangular"
            animation="pulse"
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              height: { xs: 130, sm: 150 },
            }}
          />
          <Box width="100%">
            <Skeleton
              variant="text"
              animation="pulse"
              width="100%"
              height={23}
            />
            <Skeleton
              variant="text"
              animation="pulse"
              width="100%"
              height={23}
            />
          </Box>
          <Box
            width="100%"
            display="flex"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="space-between"
          >
            <Skeleton variant="text" animation="pulse" width={52} height={23} />
          </Box>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};


I would like to create a single card with styles and then reuse it in page and swiper, but there is some issue with card wrapper styles when I put it inside page and SwiperSlide.
